# how to filter using MongoDb Aggregate when searching string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to search on the file fileName which is of type String.

```
{
 _id : ObjectId('645a42950d627800984c9f2d'),
 fileName, "untitled document (2).xlxs"
},
{
 _id : ObjectId('645a42950d627800984c9f2d'),
 fileName, "fileUpload.xlxs"
},
{
 _id : ObjectId('645a42950d627800984c9f2d'),
 fileName, "document (1).xlxs"
}
```

This is my example data.

Q1. I want to filter those data which matches my word `document`.

Expected Solution : To return 2 results

Q2. I want to filter those data which matches `untitled document (2).xlxs`.

Expected Solution : To return 1 results

How to achieve this using mongoDb aggregate.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit tried regexMatch
{
 $addFields: {
  result: {
   $regexMatch: {
    input: "$fileName",
     regex: "Ayush & Me.xlsx",
      options: "s"
   }
  }
 }
}

something like this as I didn't get anything related to filter how to use that.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit What if in one case user enters untitled document (2) this text. In this case also I need to send the data. Will the below mention with option s work ? How to work this dynamically ?

Comment: Option `s` determines whether search considers newline characters. If `fileName` is just one line, the  option `s` has no effect. Filenames must not contain newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not bad, however you need `$match` rather than `$addFields`.  And you mixed [$regexMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) with [$regex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/query/regex/).
Would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { fileName: { $regex: "document", $options: "s" } } } 
])
```

or a bit shorter:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { fileName: /document/s } }
])

db.collection.find(
   { fileName: /document/s }
)
```

and for the second one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { fileName: "untitled document (2).xlxs" } }
])

db.collection.find(
   { fileName: "untitled document (2).xlxs" }
)
```